# I am trying to print out the variable (compiled_sol), so I can deploy my smart contract, but I keep running at this error

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler, py-solc-x

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jethr\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 8, in <module>
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
  File "C:\Users\jethr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\solcx\main.py", line 394, in compile_standard
    raise SolcError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcError: Only "Solidity" or "Yul" is supported as a language.
> command: `C:\Users\jethr\.solcx\solc-v0.6.0\solc.exe --standard-json`
> return code: `0`
> stdout:
{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","message":"Only \"Solidity\" or \"Yul\" is supported as a language.","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file: Simple_Storage_file = file.read() # Compile Our Solidity 
install_solc("0.6.0") 
compiled_sol = compile_standard( { "language": "solidity", "sources": 
{"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": Simple_Storage_file}}, "settings": { 
"outputSelection": { "": {"": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", 
"evm.sourceMap"]} } }, }, solc_version="0.6.0", ) 
print(compiled_sol)
```

Comment: Here is my code below:

Comment: from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    Simple_Storage_file = file.read()

# Compile Our Solidity
install_solc("0.6.0")
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": Simple_Storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="0.6.0",
)
print(compiled_sol)

Comment: I think you have a case error, they say language can only be `Solidity` or `Yul` but you are sending `solidity`

Comment: So how can i solve it please? @JulissaDC

Comment: By using the right word with the right case